How to use Ticks formatter with Typescript in Chart.js?
If I make Chart.js to use locale en-US, I get the scale numbers formatted optimally. 
If I use tick callback like in the documents:
ticks: {
     callback: function(value) {
        return value.toString();
     }
}

I don't get optimal width for the numbers.

The aforementioned document instructs that it should be possible to combine Chart.js format and custom
Chart.Ticks.formatters.numeric.apply(this, [value, index, ticks]);

This however does not work for typescript, but I get error "Property 'Ticks' does not exist on type 'typeof Chart'."
Another variant I tried is
Chart.registry.scales.get('ticks')?.formatters.numeric.apply(this, [value, index, ticks])

in which ticks seems to exist, but I don't have a way to reach formatters. Exportable functions from helpers has only formatNumber, which requires locale, and I think that would anyway skip all the number width optimization by Chart.js.
The root cause of the problem is that my client wants the only formatting to be decimal point, and any kind of thousand separator should not exist. It will not be possible to use any kind of manual solution to format the number by cutting decimals etc, as the scale can be anything and zooming to anything is possible.
Chart.js: 4.4.2
Typescript: 4.9.4

You may try using afterTickToLabelConversion- there you already have the default string format and you may modify it. Still, if you want to access the default handler in ticks.callback, you may useChart.registry.getScale("linear").defaults.ticks.callback. Please note that Chart.registry is always available, while Chart.Ticks is only there if you use an umd version of chart.js; in a module environment you have to import it (import {Chart, Ticks} from .....).

Also, don't get stuck in basic typescript errors - the typescript layer is there to help you find errors like misspelling of an option name, not to block you from accessing something you know it's there. Making a typescript interface for a complex library as chart.js  is immensely complicated, and it can never cover all use cases. So just use casts and/or non-null assertions to get what you want.

@kikon For Chart.registry.getScale("linear").defaults.ticks.callback defaults doesn't exist, and typecasting getScale("linear") to any  gives me  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options'). afterTickToLabelConversion works.

Chart.registry.getScale("linear").defaults.ticks.callback does exist, check this fiddle; it might not be covered by chart.js typings. For a possible way to make it pass typescript, without testing, based only on looking at what exists and what doesn't in index.d.ts I'd go with (((Chart.registry.getScale("linear") as LinearScale)!.defaults as LinearScaleOptions).ticks as TickOptions).callback. That's probably paranoid, some of the castings/non-null assertions might not be necessary.

@kikon Logging a function to console is not same as calling a function. https://jsfiddle.net/u2v8d31q/ https://angular-chart-js-bkh1uf.stackblitz.io

Logging to console was in response to your function ... does not exists, which assumes I have posted something without testing. The problem with your calling of that function comes from the fact that the  default callback uses this (and user code can also do that, since this is the axis object). To make it work, you have to 1) use a "normal" function for your callback instead of an arrow function, and 2) call the default function with call or apply, see fiddle or diddle

Ah okay! It works with that one too now, thanks!

I got it working with
      afterTickToLabelConversion: (axis) => {
        axis.ticks.forEach((tick) => tick.label = tick.value?.toString());
      },

This function is called multiple times during one draw, first with initial scale (0,1), then a couple of times with different amount of ticks, ending with seven ticks visible in the chart.
